# Jquery no funciona botón limpiar

Tags: jquery, botón

El botón limpiar de un formulario no funciona.

```
<div id="error">
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>
<?php echo form_open('transaccion/mostrarDatosTransaccion'); ?>
<div id="contact">
  <h1 align='center'>Transacción</h2>
    <form id="formulario_transaccion">
      <fieldset>
        <label for="texDescripcion">Descripción </label>
        <input
          type="text" name="texDescripcion"
          id="texDescripcion" value="<?php echo set_value('texDescripcion', '');?>"/>
        <br />
        <div id="botones">
          <input
            type="submit" name="guardarTransaccion"
            id="guardarTransaccion" value="Guardar Transacción" />                                          
          <button
            type="reset" name="limpiar"
            id="limpiar" value="LIMPIAR" >LIMPIAR</button>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>

  <?php echo form_close(); ?>

  <br />
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://localhost/CesdeCodeIgniter/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $("#limpiar").click(function(event) {
    $("#formulario_transaccion")[0].reset();
  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que imprimen las funciones `form_open()` y `form_close()`? No estás duplicando la etiqueta `form`?

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#limpiar").click(function(event) {
        $("#formulario_transaccion")[0].reset();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

El reset de un form vuelve los valores de sus campos a los que tenía al cargarse, para "vaciar" los campos hay que setear el value, algo así:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="error">
  <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
</div>
<?php echo form_open('transaccion/mostrarDatosTransaccion'); ?>
<div id="contact">
  <h1 align='center'>Transacción</h1>
  <form id="formulario_transaccion">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <label for="texDescripcion">Descripción </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="texDescripcion" id="texDescripcion" value="si me editas y presionas &quot;limpiar&quot;, vuelvo a aparecer" /></div>
<br />
<div id="botones">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="guardarTransaccion" id="guardarTransaccion" value="Guardar Transacción" />
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" name="limpiar" id="limpiar" value="LIMPIAR">LIMPIAR</button>

  <button class="btn btn-danger" name="vaciar" id="vaciar" value="VACIAR">VACIAR</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<br />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $("#limpiar").click(function(event) {
    $("#formulario_transaccion")[0].reset();
  });

  $("#vaciar").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#formulario_transaccion")
      .find("input[type=text], textarea")
      .val("");
  });
  //*/
</script>
```